# $and operator does not return any result in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi EveryOne I'm beginner in MongoDB.I want to return some documents in mongodb. I'm using NodeJS. I have multiple documents in collections.In my case I want to **return documents which have column called make both 2002 and 2008** and I need return columns only name.Thanks in advance....

```html
 My code:
    db.collection('cars').find( 
                {$and:[ {$in:{make:{2002,2008}} ]}
                ,{name:1,_id:0},(err,doc)=>{
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                else{
                    console.log(doc);
                }});



                I have collections in my db:

                /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cddda829719b0234ccef10d"),
        "name" : "Posche",
        "make" : 2002,
        "price" : 2300000
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cdee01d1f92122b785874ba"),
        "name" : "Audi",
        "make" : 2002,
        "price" : 2300000
    }

    /* 3 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cdee01d1f92122b785874bb"),
        "name" : "BMW",
        "make" : 2003,
        "price" : 2000000
    }

    /* 4 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cdee01d1f92122b785874bc"),
        "name" : "Toyoto",
        "make" : 2005,
        "price" : 1500000
    }

    /* 5 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cdee3e71f0e0ab8a16cb2c8"),
        "make" : 2008,
        "name" : "Volvo",
        "price" : 59862
    }


    My Expected output:

    [{"name" : "Posche"},
     {"name" : "Audi"},
     {"name" : "volvo"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you seem to be looking for is:

`db.collection('cars').find({ make: {$in:[2002,2008]},{name:1,_id:0},` ... rest of your code

This will return documents which `make` matches any of those two years.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Instead of this any method available?

Comment: You can use $and as well but you $in in this case seems to give you what you are after no? It would also be shorter and cleaner.